# combination of MSCA Fellowship with a position of assistant professor

Tags: marie-curie

Can a MSCA Fellowship (IF/EF) be combined or cumulated with a position of Assistant Professor (only for some months)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Based on contract, it is not allowed, MSCA is very restrictive grant

Comment: I agree with @looktook , 99% that is is explicitly not allowed. Certainly was prohibited in my MSCA EF

Comment: yes, I know many people who need to give up of MSCA because they got position MSCA traps you in postdoc stage @demitau

Answer (score -1):

Based on the contract, no, it is not possible. MSCA is a very restrictive grant. It traps you at the postdoc stage.